# Difference between numpy.round and numpy.around

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

So, I was searching for ways to round off all the numbers in a numpy array. I found 2 similar functions, numpy.round and numpy.around. Both take seemingly same arguments for a beginner like me.

So what is the difference between these two in terms of:

- General difference
- Speed
- Accuracy
- Being used in practice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[They are the exact same function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2840-L2851):

```
def round_(a, decimals=0, out=None):
    """
    Round an array to the given number of decimals.
    Refer to `around` for full documentation.
    See Also
    --------
    around : equivalent function
    """
    return around(a, decimals=decimals, out=out)
```

Comment: Documentation says: np.round - Round an array to the given number of decimals. and for np.around -  Evenly round to the given number of decimals.

Answer (score 11):

The main difference is that `round` is a `ufunc` of the `ndarray` class, while `np.around` is a module-level function.

Functionally, both of them are equivalent as they do the same thing - evenly round floats to the nearest integer. `ndarray.round` calls `around` from within its source code.

Comment: What exactly is a ufunc?

Comment: @DuttaA "Universal Function". These are methods of `ndarray` which operate elementwise on arrays.

Comment: Thanks...appreciate the help

Comment: @cs95 What is mean by "evenly round"? What is the difference with "round" ?

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2023, the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) now says
`around` is an alias of `round`.